# org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod of Commons HttpClient 3.0.1 replacement in httpcomponents HttpClient 4.5.1?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

We are migrating from Commons HttpClient 3.0.1 to httpcomponents HttpClient 4.5.1.
Currently we are facing an issue related to HttpMethod class which is not present in the migrating version(httpcomponents HttpClient 4.5.1). We are performing the operation of "getResponseHeader()" from the HttpMthod class.

Is there any replacement available for the HttpMethod in "httpcomponents HttpClient 4.5.1"? If not Is there any other way to get "getResponseHeader()"  using "httpcomponents HttpClient 4.5.1"?

Comment: Even I have the same doubt.I ended up using separate methods i.e one for Get and one for Post .Its better to use both separately since HttpUriRequest won't suffice all the requirements related to methods

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a common interface of all http methods, use HttpUriRequest:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
HttpUriRequest get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpUriRequest post = new HttpPost(url);

...
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create.build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get or post);
```

all response related properties (headers, return code and output stream) could be accessed by response object which is more sensible!